# R returning partial matching of row names

Tags: r, dataframe, matching, r-rownames

I've run into the following issue

```
vec <- c("a11","b21","c31")
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,0,0), b = c(1,1,1), row.names = vec)
df["a",]
```

returns

```
df["a",]
    a b
a11 0 1
```

However,

```
"a" %in% vec
```

and

```
"a" %in% rownames(df)
```

both return False

R is allowing for partial matching of the string when using letter followed by numbers for row names. I have replicated this on R v3.2.2 and R v3.2.1.
Even

```
df[["a",1,exact=T]]
```

returns 0.

Is there anything I can set such that R does not allow this partial matching?

Comment: If you are looking for an option to turn it off, there isn't one.  Similar but fairly uneventful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033501/warning-when-partial-matching-rownames

Answer (score 5):

Weird, didn't even realize the partial matching was a thing.

Instead of indexing into the dataframe directly, you could try to identify records that exact match on rowname separately and construct an indexing vector from the result, like so:

```
> ix <- 'a' == row.names(df)
> df[ix,]
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

or equivalently (but more concisely):

```
> df['a' == row.names(df),]
```

Alternatively, if you coerce the object to a data.table it will only return exact matches:

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(df)
> dt[,ix := vec]
> setkey(dt, ix)

> dt['a']
    a  b ix
1: NA NA  a

> dt['a11']
   a b  ix
1: 0 1 a11
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not try:

```
df[grep(pattern = "a", x = rownames(df)),]
```

Which would return:

> ```
> > df[grep(pattern = "a", x = rownames(df)),]
>     a b
> a11 0 1
> ```

Making use of `grep` would provide you with addittional flexibility, for example if you want to match row names that would have **a** only:

> ```
> > df[grep(pattern = "^a$", x = rownames(df)),]
> [1] a b
> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> ```